# Multiple array matches using preg_matches

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, sphinx

we are doing one project regarding tagging analysis based on members data. But we need to know how we can matches more than one array values using preg_matches in php. Because each tag having the more than one values. Incase any one of that values matched with member data, we need to assign that tag for that member. As well as we need a count that is how many word matched in the given string.

So please share your ideas.

Comment: Do you have an example of the returned result you want to manipulate?  It sounds like you are searching by a tag array, and also want to count those tag matches against another field in each document?

Comment: You might do data aggregation and matching directly on MongoDB using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation). Since the heavy work will be done in C++, you gain performance rather doing via PHP with raw data.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have already figured out a way or another way as this question is very old.

Still if it helps you then I will suggest you to use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) This gives you to apply user defined function to all elements of the all arrays you passed to it.

You can use it for your matching purpose with bits of tricks and it will deliver you the desire result set.

Also if you have figured out any better way or any way of doing what you want you can share that too with us. :)